# In MongoDB Compass data inserted with Node aren't visible (are visible only if I close Compass and reconnect)

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongodb-compass

I'm using Node.js and I'm implementing a "toy recipe rest api". I have this post

```js
router.post("/recipes", async (req, res) => {
    
const data = new Recipes({
  nome: req.body.name,
});
    
const newRecipe = await data.save();

return res.status(201).send(newRecipe);
    });
```

and this model:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
    
const dataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  nome: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});
    
let dataModel = mongoose.model("recipes", dataSchema);
    
export { dataModel };
```

Above I defined the schema of the collection "recipes" and with the post. I want insert the recipe sent in the body of the post request (sent with postman).

I'm using MongoDB Compass as a service. It seems all right, but my problem is that in Compass I can't see the `document` inserted with the code. When I refresh I don't see anything. But if I close Compass and reopen it data inserted with Node are there. What could be the problem and how could I resolve?

I'm on Windows 11.

Comment: you are having an issue with compass application, so this is probably the wrong place to ask. There are several "refresh" features in compass, so it isn't clear what problem you might be having.

Comment: it kind of sounds like you might be doing "refresh databases" when you need to run the query again.

Comment: I put the discussion here why I'm newbye about Node and Mongo and I don't know if the problem is the code or the program.  For refresh I mean the refresh inside Compass programm.  Furthermore I saw if I create a new Collection or a new document (inside the compass programm) the documents inserted with Node application are displayed in Compass: thus the problem could be about Compass application. Where I could ask?

Comment: I think maybe `https://dba.stackexchange.com/`, but I'm not sure.
but, yes, if you insert using compass it automatically runs the query again. I think you probably just need to hit FIND button to run the query again

Comment: But, compass doesn't have just a "refresh". There is a "refresh databases" button, which reloads databases and collection names. There is a View-Reload option in menu. There is a "FIND" button to run a search query.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey I solved it through your suggestion. I was basically hitting the wrong refresh button. Thanks.